# Show images stored in mysql database + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, image

I want to show the images stored in my database in my View.
I have a field "deliverable_image" from the type "longblob" in my mysql database.

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Show( int id )
    {
        var imageData = repository.GetAllImages();

        return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
    }
```

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<byte[]> GetAllImages()
    {
        return from deliverable in entities.deliverables
               orderby deliverable.deliverable_image
               select deliverable.deliverable_image;
    }
```

View:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "Show", "Deliverable", new { id = ViewData["DeliverableID"] } ) %>' />
```

But in my controller I get the error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'

Does anybody knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action method, the very first line gets a collection of images (specifically, an `IQueryable<byte[]>`:

```
var imageData = repository.GetAllImages();
```

Then you try to send all of the images as a single file:

```
return File(imageData, "image/jpg");
```

`imageData` is a collection of files.  You need to select one of them and return just that.  To do that, you'll probably need to modify your `GetAllImages` function or use a different function.  The action method is being passed an `id`, but you can't use that on the results of that function because all you have are byte arrays.  You need to filter for the `id` specified and then use the resulting byte array.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in my repository?

Comment: @niels123: You can either pass the `id` to the repository function and add a `where` clause to the LINQ statement, or return more than just the byte array (an object, basically) from the repository and filter with a `.Where()` when calling the repository function.  I personally prefer the latter, as it makes sense to me that a repository is a place to get and persist objects, not just pieces of data.